# Sorting array values using Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

I'm trying to output a list of items pulled from an API we use to connect to our MDM console. I have two functions, both of which work together and I can see all the data in the output of the script, however, I would like to sort this data into a .csv file using the variable names from one of the functions as the column headers. I'm new to PS and have been pulling my hair out.
I can see that the variable is an array and all the values in there, but have zero idea how to sort if or if there is a better way to grab the data I need.

```
    #Current MDM Environment
    $ev = "Q"

    #Define MDM credentials to match environment from above
    if($ev -eq "Q")
    {
    $Code = 'VbvmMGOV0Pd2lF4GurpBqnwD/R6mFmUKI6z3CKAY5tw='
    $ui = 'MDMqualserver'
    }
    else{$Code = 'Pe8w/3jDREgse2gUu3UYZ28FHeafg0xcheu/AYwJ6PE='
    $ui = 'MDMprodserver'}#>


    #API Auth for MDM Console
    $Auth = Get-Content -path 'C:\ProgramData\ScriptAuth\mobilityapi.txt'

    $Contenttype = 'application/json'

    $CurrentDate = Get-Date
    $CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')

    $path = "C:\users\username\desktop\$currentDate.csv"

    Function get_all
    {
    $array =@()

    #Define URL
    $url = "https://$ui.company.gov/api/mdm/devices/extensivesearch? 
    pagesize=10000"

    #Define Headers
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String], 
    [String]]"
    $headers.Add("aw-tenant-code", $Code)
    $headers.Add("Authorization", $Auth)

    #Send Rest Request
    try{
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Headers $headers}
    catch{
    $error = "BDevice Info Not Found"}

    #Close Connection
    $ServicePoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint($url)
    $SSP = $ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("")
    #Parse Device Info
    $data = $response.DeviceExtensiveSearchResult.Devices.DeviceDetailsExt

    $data | foreach {
    $serial = $_.SerialNumber
    $array += $serial
    }
    return $array
    }

    Function get_devattrib
    {
    Param([string]$serial)

    $array = @()

    #Define URL
    $url = "https://$ui.company.gov/api/mdm/devices? 
    searchby=Serialnumber&id=$serial"

    #Define Headers
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String], 
    [String]]"
    $headers.Add("aw-tenant-code", $Code)
    $headers.Add("Authorization", $Auth)
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", $Contenttype)

    #Send Rest Request
    try{
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Headers $headers}
    catch{
    return $false}

    #Close Connection
    $ServicePoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint($url)
    $ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("")

    #Parse Device Info (#removed .Device from $data = $response.Device)
    $data = $response

    $data | foreach {
    $ownership = $_.Ownership 
    $friendlyname = $_.DeviceFriendlyName
    $platform = $_.Platform 
    $model = $_.Model 
    $snumber = $_.AssetNumber
    $username = $_.UserName
    $mac = $_.MacAddress
    $phone = $_.PhoneNumber
    $lastseen = $_.LastSeen
    $enrollstatus = $_.EnrollmentStatus
    $compliance = $_.ComplianceStatus 


    return [datetime]$lastseen, $ownership, $friendlyname, $platform, $model, 
    $snumber, $serial, $username, $mac, $phone, $enrollstatus, $compliance
    }
    }

    $devices = @()
    $getdevices = @()

    $devices = get_all 

    foreach ($device in $devices){

       $getdevices += get_devattrib $device  
    }

    $getdevices
```

The output of the data looks like this for each device in our console (I have made the info generic to hide company data):

> True
>
> Wednesday, September 5, 2018 8:33:21 PM Corporate Owned username - assetnumber Apple iPad Pro with Wi-Fi + Cellular (128 GB Space Gray) asset number serial nubmer username mac address phonenumber Enrolled NonCompliant

A. I don't understand why I get "true" at the beginning of the output for each device in the console and the space afterwards (which seems to come with the `[datetime]`)

B. I don't understand how to place all this data in a .csv file. I do have a path defined before the functions and know how to use export-csv, but the data that it sends to the file appears as just `#TYPE System.Boolean` so I'm assuming there is something wrong with my last variable. Whew.

Comment: this line `$ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("")` looks like it may return something. have you checked to see if that is the source of the `True`? ///// the way to get the data into a CSV file is to keep it as an array of objects OR to build an array of custom objects. you have broken the "object-ness" with the `$data | foreach {` section where you disassemble the object into individual $Vars. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it does indeed (`[System.Net.ServicePoint].GetMethod('CloseConnectionGroup').ReturnType`)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - thank you for the confirmation! i appreciate it ... and so will the OP. [*grin*]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can sort with `Sort-Object`.

```
$ArrayOfStrings = 's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k'
$ArrayOfStrings | Sort-Object
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments guys. I am going to attempt what Lee_Dailey has suggested an "unbreak" the array and sort it out later.